# Wildfly: An automatic redirect to the Administration Console is not currently available

Tags: wildfly

Не открывается administration console wildfly. Нашел способ исправления запустить сервер с настройками `sudo /opt/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh -b=0.0.0.0 -bmanagement=0.0.0.0` Однако получаю ошибку

```
9:08:51,750 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-1) MSC000001: 
Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default:
Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8080
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:209)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)


19:08:52,237 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: Failed to start service org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.management.http.extensible: java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:9990
        at org.jboss.as.server.mgmt.UndertowHttpManagementService.start(UndertowHttpManagementService.java:399)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

19:08:52,410 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC000001: 
Failed to start service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https: 
Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8443
        at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.ListenerService.start(ListenerService.java:209)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1739)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.execute(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1701)
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ControllerTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1559)
        at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
        at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1363)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

19:08:52,422 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:9990"}}
19:08:52,571 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("http-listener" => "default")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.undertow.listener.default" => "Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8080"}}
19:08:52,577 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "undertow"),
    ("server" => "default-server"),
    ("https-listener" => "https")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.undertow.listener.https" => "Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8443"}}
19:08:52,578 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0459: Triggering roll back due to missing management services.
19:08:52,582 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("core-service" => "management"),
    ("management-interface" => "http-interface")
]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"org.wildfly.management.http.extensible" => "java.net.BindException: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:9990"}}
```

Comment: Address already in use /0.0.0.0:8080. По какому адресу открываете консоль администратора при обычном запуске?

Comment: это удаленный сервер debian. hostname/console

Comment: Какой командой вы пытаетесь открыть консоль администратора? На самом сервере локально открывается?

Comment: к серверу подключаюсь через vpn и ssh и работаю через командную строку. сам wildfly доступен из интернета.

Comment: Если вы хотите подключиться к консоли администратора wildfly через терминал, необходимо запустить утилиту wildfly-dir/bin/jboss-cli.sh. Далее connect 127.0.0.1:9990 (9990 - порт администратора по умолчанию).

Comment: и далее deploy filename.war?

Comment: Примерно так. Двойное нажатие tab показывает доступные команды.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<interfaces>
    <interface name="management">
        <any-address />
    </interface>
    <interface name="public">
        <any-address />
    </interface>
</interfaces>
```